# multiple JQuery datepicker fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a form with multiple JQuery datepicker fields, but the problem is the first 2 fields only work and the rest not , i searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22828440/multiple-datepicker-in-same-page-not-working-javascript) , but didn't help., here is my code :

```
$('.datePicker').datepicker({
changeYear: true,
changeMonth: true,
autoSize: true,
dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
maxDate: "0y",
showAnim: "show",
yearRange:'c-70:c+0',

});
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" class='datePicker' name='startDate' ><span><img alt="" src="${assetPath(src: 'calendar-icon.png')}"/></span>
<input type="text" class='datePicker' name='endDate' ><span><img alt="" src="${assetPath(src: 'calendar-icon.png')}"/></span>
```

Comment: As long as they all have the class `.datePicker` it should work. There's no need for a loop as the plugin does that internally anyway.

Comment: @adeneo , this what suppose to happen but i don't know what is wrong

Comment: You've only posted two fields, that seem [to work just fine](https://jsfiddle.net/pbsucbn1/), what does the other fields look like ?

Comment: @adeneo, these 2 fields are duplicated 4 times . these are all the fields related to the datepicker

Comment: That still seems to [**work just fine**](https://jsfiddle.net/pbsucbn1/1/), so something else must be wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.datePicker').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
    changeYear: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    autoSize: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    maxDate: "0y",
    showAnim: "show",
    yearRange:'c-70:c+0',
    });
});
```

Comment: didn't help , still the same issue